# Set initial section for a Hub control

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

Is there a way to set the initially visible section for a HubControl, while keeping the order intact? Using DefaultSectionIndex moves any previous sections to the end, while using

```
HubControl.ScrollToSection(1)
```

In the constructor of the Page snaps the section into view. I would like either that section to start visible or for there to be a smooth scroll to section 1 once the page is visilbe.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by DefaultSelectionIndex moves any previous sections to the end? A Hub will wrap around; using DefaultSelectionIndex does preserve the order. It just so happens that if you continue scrolling right, the previous index to your DefaultSelectionIndex will be at the end; however, if you immediately scroll to the left of your DefaultSelectionIndex, then the previous section should still be there.

I think using DefaultSelectionIndex is your answer.

Comment: IF you use DefaultSectionIndex, the title at the top Left aligns to the DefaultSectionIndex, and the wrap around obviously starts there. I want it to look like the Hub starts at index 0, but first shows a different index.

Comment: I see what you mean, not sure the best way to work around it. Maybe there is a way to have the HubControl scroll to the section before navigating to the HubPage, which would hopefully hide the snapping effect. Let me know if you figure something out!